# Django API request is empty using React

Tags: python, django, api, reactjs

So I am using axios in order to send a JSON request to Django API.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' + this.state.dataRequestEndPoint,
  data: (reqData)
});
```

Just before the axios call I can see the request:

```
Object {nvm: "", a: Array(1), b: Array(1), c: Array(1), d: Array(1)}
```

However, when it gets to Django:

```
class TargetClass(APIView):
  def get(self, request):
     Here request is empty:
       (Pdb) request.data
       <QueryDict: {}>
       (Pdb) request.body
       b''
  def post(self):
      pass
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Tried to send the request with `fetch` as well:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/' + this.state.dataRequestEndPoint, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: reqData,
})
```

None of it works.

Comment: Have you checked how its being sent in the networks part of a browser ? Like in the developer tools of any browser.

Comment: Have you tried your endpoint using API testing tools like postman or something?

Comment: In the networks tab it looks ok. I haven't tried any tools, as I thought that when I manage to hit from the url it should be fine? The thing is that I need to pass those parameters in order to return the appropriate data.

Comment: Looks like you're object isn't in the correct format. You need to JSON.parse or JSON.stringify perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the problem above. Apparently, axios needs to send parameters:

```
var reqData = this.state.requestParams
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' + this.state.dataRequestEndPoint,
    params: {
      'a': reqData['a'],
      'b': reqData['b']
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  });
```

However, I don't know how good this solution is security-wise.

Comment: Why is it unsafe to do what you mentioned? Is it because if params?